# How to map an entity to a table from a certain server

Tags: symfony, orm, doctrine, mapping

I'm new to doctrine and I don't understand how doctrine knows to map an entity to a table if I have more than one connection.

Let's say we have 2 connections to different servers: connection1 and connection2. Both servers have a table called history_table.

So my entity would look like this:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="history_table")
 */
class Entity {
}
```

How doctrine knows what connection do I want to use? Is there an annotation for that as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just configure own entity manager for every connection. Both of them are work with the same entity classes:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        connections:
            connection_foo:
                driver: …
                host: …
                dbname: …
                user: …
                password: …
            connection_bar:
                driver: …
                host: …
                dbname: …
                user: …
                password: …
    orm:
        entity_managers:
            foo:
                connection: connection_foo
                mappings:
                    YourBundle: ~
            bar:
                connection: connection_bar
                mappings:
                    YourBundle: ~
```

Documentation: [How to Work with multiple Entity Managers and Connections](http://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/multiple_entity_managers.html)

> How doctrine knows what connection do I want to use? Is there an annotation for that as well?

The Doctrine does not know that. You have to choose it yourself.